# XAMPP con Node js

Tags: php, javascript, nodejs, xampp

necesito ayuda, tengo un proyecto con socket estoy haciendo el socket con node js, pero el node me crea un servidor quisiera usar de servidor al xampp para que por ahi me lleguen las peticiones del cliente al socket. Como podría configurar esto de manera que salgo por el puerto de mi modem el 8080. Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: El servidor no es XAMPP, el servidor es APACHE. A lo que sé, Node crea su propio web server con el módulo htttp y he visto que se configuran las peticiones con Nginx, pero el server y el puerto te lo crea node

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que en Xampp tienes varias aplicaciones web corriendo.
Y lo que quieres es añadir una aplicación web hecha en node.

Una forma de hacerlo es usar el modulo de apache Mod_Proxy (proxy inverso / reverse proxy).

Básicamente lo que haría el modulo reverse-proxy es redirigir determinadas conexiones web (en función del dominio y la url) a la ip:puerto donde esta escuchando la aplicación Node Js.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass "/nodeapp" "http://127.0.0.1:1880/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/nodeapp" "http://127.0.0.1:1880/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Según esto el apache redirigirá todas las conexiones
que tengan **/nodeapp**  a la ip **127.0.0.1** y el puerto **1880** donde se supone que esta la aplicación en nodejs.

Para estas tareas es mas fácil de configurar ngnix.
Para mas información busca "apache reverse proxy node js"

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP y Node.js son cosas diferentes, Xampp solo es un programa que te facilita el correr tu servidor en apache, pero podrías hacerlo en la consola (MacOS & linux) con `username$ apachectl start` y para hacerlo con Nodejs es `../Proyecto/ $node server.js`. Esto significa que si hiciste un REST API con node no puedes correrlo con XAMPP, tendrás que configurar los puertos y las ip en el archivo de node, si quieres probarlo local puedes usar localhost y el puerto que desees, si quieres un servidor web puedes usar [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/)

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió tu respuesta.